# How to turn an ASCII value back into a character

Tags: c#, ascii

I have a text message i have converted to ASCII. I've then used the ASCII value and  a keyword to convert the ASCII value to that of its corresponding letter in a unique alphabet. How would i convert the ASCII number back into a character. I currently am using characteres 97 - 122

```
foreach (char c in txtEncryption.Text) // Finding ascii values for each character
{
    byte[] TempAsciiValue = Encoding.ASCII.getChars(c); // Fix,,,

    string TempAsciiValStr = TempAsciiValue.ToString();
    int TempAsciiVal = int.Parse(TempAsciiValStr);

    if (TempAsciiVal == 32)
    {
        ArrayVal[Count] = TempAsciiVal;
    }
    else
    { 
        // Calculations
        int Difference = TempAsciiVal - 65; // Finds what letter after A it is
        int TempValue = ArrayAlphabet[Count, 1]; // Find the starting ASCII value for new alphabet
        int TempValuePlusDifference = TempValue + Difference;

        //Convert the ASCII value to the letter

        ArrayVal[Count] = TempValuePlusDifference; //Store the letters ASCII code

        Count++;

        if (Count > 3)
        {
            Count = 1;
        }
    }
    for (int d = 1; d < CountMessageLength; d++)
    {
        string TempArrayVal = ArrayVal[Count].ToString();
        txtEncryption2.Text = TempArrayVal;
        // Convert TempArrayVal to = Letter (TempLetterStorage),,,,
        // String FinalMessage = all TempLetterStorage values
    }
}
```

Comment: If you aren't married to the idea of processing ASCII, you could use UTF-16, .NET's (and Java, and JavaScript, and [effectively] VB4/5/6/A/Script, etc) native character encoding for the Unicode character set. You might still just focus on the [Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) letters. For them, each letter is one UTF-16 code unit (`char`). That would simplify your algorithms. Would that make sense in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with bytes that are ASCII character codes, say for the sake of this exercise, 97 to 122

```
Byte[] asciiBytes = Enumerable.Range(97, 122 + 1 - 97).Select(i => (Byte)i).ToArray();
```

Use an encoding object for the ASCII encoding, with desirable behaviors, to whit: validate our assumption that the input character codes are in the ASCII range:

```
Encoding asciiEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(
    Encoding.ASCII.CodePage, 
    EncoderFallback.ExceptionFallback, 
    DecoderFallback.ExceptionFallback)
```

Decode to a .NET `String` (UTF-16)

```
String text = asciiEncoding.GetString(asciiBytes);
```

Comment: I changed my code to the code at its current state. This is my loop for attempting to take the message i have convert it to its ascii value for each letter and then after converting it to my other alphabet changing the ascii value back to its letter form to then output. I however have an error when creating the ascii bytes and im not sure why? is it because im using .getchars?

Comment: Also is the way i do it the best way to convert the ascii code to an integer? By converting it to a string outputting that to a value then changing that value to an int?

Comment: ASCII is foreign to .NET. So, codes are in Byte[]. asciiEncoding.GetBytes(text)